# App Registration issue in Azure Active Directory, the app is not in the tenant?

Tags: xamarin.forms, azure-active-directory

[image]I am having an issue with Azure Active Directory App Registration.
The app is created by my supervisor who have some admin permissions.

What should we do to confirm that we have admin permission and what other issues could have caused this?

Comment: I've seen this happen if you mix v1 and v2 endpoints. What URL are you hitting in your app to authenticate? Are you using MSAL or ADAL? Was the app registered in Azure Portal or the apps.dev.microsoft.com site?

Comment: This sample app is using ADAL. The URL is the correct redirection and tenant is correct. I was able to login to that tenant in ASP.NET project. The issue is in the app registration most likely. The app was registered by my supervisor. Could it be as the error indicate, he doesn't have admin privileges?

Comment: I doubt the problem is admin privileges. Check with them where they registered the app.

Answer (score 2):

Your application needs to be registered under your Azure Active Directory tenant. It is okay to have subscriptions and resources in another tenant, and you can even deploy the app to a resource group under a different tenant, but the registration itself must be under your AAD tenant.

Even if this is set correctly, this error sometimes also occurs when your APP ID/Client ID, tenant ID, or Client Secret settings in your config or app settings do not match what's in the portal. Check to ensure that these match exactly. If you have the permission to do this, you can delete the old app registration and re-register the app under the proper tenant.